# how to replace particular occurence of string with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, angular

here is the code,it's  for one single line string but it's not working for the multiline text.
i'm extracting data from xml file .

```
let xmlData = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RecipeData>
    <SUNDAY Value="1"/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <MONDAY Value="1"/>
    </MONDAY>
    <MONDAY>
    </MONDAY>
    </RecipeData>`;
    search = '<SUNDAY/>'
    let n = 2
    console.log(xmlData.replace(RegExp("((<SUNDAY(\s*)\/(\s*)>)$\g){" + n + "}"), function(x){return x.replace(RegExp("((<SUNDAY(\s*)\/(\s*)>)$\g)" + "$"), "HHHH")}))
```

Expected output :

We are replacing the second occurance of the

```
`<SUNDAY with HHHH.`
```

So the output will be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RecipeData>
        <SUNDAY Value="1"/>
        <HHHHH/>
        <SUNDAY/>
        <SUNDAY/>
        <MONDAY Value="1"/>
        </MONDAY>
        <MONDAY>
        </MONDAY>
        </RecipeData>;
```

Comment: You are not matching line breaks anywhere. How do you expect the regex to match a multiline block of text? Besides, you have no backslashes in the pattern string. `"\s"` = `"s"`. Why do you have `\g` in the pattern?

Comment: Why mess round with XML using regex in the first place?

Comment: Should include your expected output.

Comment: Expected output has been included

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and for example count the occurrences where `nodeName` equals `SUNDAY`.

If there is a match, replace the node with a new node through the parentNode.

```js
let xmlData = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RecipeData>
    <SUNDAY Value="1"/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <MONDAY Value="1">
    </MONDAY>
    <MONDAY>
    </MONDAY>
</RecipeData>`,
  search = 'SUNDAY',
  n = 2;

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData, "text/xml");
let childNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
let nrSundays = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
  if (childNodes[i].nodeName === search) {
    nrSundays++;
    if (nrSundays === n) {
      let childNode = childNodes[i];
      childNode.parentNode.replaceChild(xmlDoc.createElement('HHHHH'), childNode);
    }
  }
}

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement));
```

---

Another option could be using xpath using [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

```js
let xmlData = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RecipeData>
    <SUNDAY Value="1"/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <SUNDAY/>
    <MONDAY Value="1">
    </MONDAY>
    <MONDAY>
    </MONDAY>
</RecipeData>`,
  search = 'SUNDAY',
  n = 2;

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData, "text/xml");
let nodeSunday = xmlDoc.evaluate(`/RecipeData/${search}[${n}]`, xmlDoc.documentElement, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
nodeSunday.singleNodeValue.parentNode.replaceChild(xmlDoc.createElement('HHHH'), nodeSunday.singleNodeValue);
console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement));
```

Another